# Multilevel in shiny input

Tags: r, shiny, data.table

I have, multilevel in my shiny UI input like **Region**, **Province** and **school**.

`library(data.table)
      selectInput("Region","Region",c("GOLFE","MARITIME","KARA","SAVANES"))
      selectInput("Province","Province", as.character(sort(unique(dt[,Region]))))
      selectInput("School","School",as.character(sort(unique(dt[,Province]))))`

How can I do the link with Region -> Province -> School.
Thank

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do that on the server side, using the updateSelectInput function.